Select unique second column per each fist column with minimal value of third column
Using postgres, is it possible or how to select from table below distinct value of id and id2? :



id
id2
a
b
a1
b1




1
2
150
200
200
200


2
2
150
200
200
200


3
2
150
200
200
200


1
4
150
200
200
200


2
4
150
200
200
200


3
4
150
200
200
200



I need to select distinct values of id, such as id2 is also distinct, and the differences between a and b, and then a1 and b2 are minimal.
For the example above, this should be only two rows, since there are only two distinct values in id2
Correct



id
id2
a
b
a1
b1




1
2
150
200
200
200


2
4
150
200
200
200



I was trying to make it work via
distinct on(rank() over (order by b - a, a1 - b1, id)
Even if I try to select twice, like select over select, it doesn't help much, so I'm a bit stuck.
For now I only got this, which is not correct:
Incorrect



id
id2
a
b
a1
b1




1
2
150
200
200
200


1
4
150
200
200
200



with data as (
select 1 id, 1 as id2, 150 a, 200 b, 200 a1, 150 b1
union
select 1 id, 2 as id2, 150 a, 150 b, 200 a1, 200 b1
union
select 1 id, 3 as id2, 150 a, 100 b, 200 a1, 100 b1
union
select 1 id, 4 as id2, 150 a, 150 b, 200 a1, 200 b1
union
select 2 id, 1 as id2, 150 a, 200 b, 200 a1, 150 b1
union
select 2 id, 2 as id2, 150 a, 150 b, 200 a1, 200 b1
union
select 2 id, 3 as id2, 150 a, 100 b, 200 a1, 100 b1
union
select 2 id, 4 as id2, 150 a, 150 b, 200 a1, 200 b1
union
select 3 id, 1 as id2, 150 a, 200 b, 200 a1, 150 b1
union
select 3 id, 4 as id2, 150 a, 150 b, 200 a1, 200 b1
union
select 3 id, 3 as id2, 150 a, 100 b, 200 a1, 100 b1
union
select 3 id, 2 as id2, 150 a, 150 b, 200 a1, 200 b1
)
select *
from data
where b >= a  and b1 >= a1
order by  id2, b - a, a1 - b1, rank() over (order by id2, id);


With six pairs for (id, id2, a, b) = (1|4|1|1), (1|5|1|2), (1|6|1|10), (2|4|1|1), (2|5|1|2), (2|6|1|10), (3|4|1|3), (3|5|1|3), (3|6|1|100), which combination do you want? Would it be okay to end up with   (1|4|1|1) which is lowest for id 1, (2|5|1|2) which is second lowest for id 2, because lowest would clash with id 1, and (3|6|1|100) for id 3, which is only third lowest for id 2, because lowest two would clash with id 1 and 2? In that case the total (b-a) would be very high, because of the chosen row for id 3. Would that matter? Must we find the minimum sum(b-a)?

And with ony the following five pairs for (id, id2, a, b) = (1|4|1|1), (1|5|1|3), (2|4|1|3), (2|6|1|1), (3|4|1|10), which combination would you want now? If we choose (1|4|1|1) for id 1 and (2|6|1|1) for id 2, then we can't take (3|4|1|10) and end up with a sum(b-a) of 0. Or must we use all IDs if possible? Then we'd get (1|5|1|3), (2|6|1|1) and (3|4|1|10) with a sum(b-a) = 11. So, what are the exact rules, which rows to choose?

Your example is not very good, because with all values being the same, we don't really see you deciding for particular rows depending on differences. Anyway, you'll end up with some recursive query to solve this in SQL.

@ThorstenKettner for would it be okay question, actually I sorted by difference to achieve lowest diff between b and a, so finding non conflicting minimum is part of the goal, right.
Per your second question, yes, we need to get maximum possible Id pairs as a result.
May be it helps, but generally set of id2 are repeating for each of id, as I am basically choosing best much between two tables basing on some selection criteria (ie partition), as you can see in my example

in addition, id is linked with a, and id2 with b,
they are from same rows, so it is not possible for id2=4 to have different values like 1 and 3, 10 for b.
if we ignore this, than (1|5|1|3), (2|6|1|1) and (3|4|1|10)  is quite fine as outcome

You've lost me. This is not one table, but two tables? One with the unique column id and another column a, and the other with the unique column id2 and another column b? And the table you are showing is actually a query result of the two tables? Yes? The IDs are unique in their respective table, so we will always see the same a value for an id and the same b value for an id2? How do a1 and a2 come into play? Are they from the same tables or other tables? Is the table you are showing just the cartesian product of table1 and table2, i.e. all possible row combinations?

E.g. if you add the row (4, 4, etc), do you expect it to be returned or not? Why?

@jarlh: They dismissed (3, 4, ...), so they'll also dismiss (4, 4, ...), because for id2 = 4 they already have (3, 4, ...) in the results. Anyway, the comment "id is linked with a, and id2 with b, they are from same rows" seems to indicate some cartesian (?) join from two tables here, producing the rows shown, thus making certain combinations impossible (" it is not possible for id2=4 to have different values like 1 and 3, 10 for b"). I'll wait for this to be answered before thinking about a solution :-)

@ThorstenKettner, sorry for missing the details, I was trying to create something simple as example.
Yes, you are completely right, id, a, a1 are from "first table" and id1, b, b1 are from "second". They are actually only examples
Btw, what you mean by "recursive query" could you show some link?

@Павел: Thank you for clarifying this. I'll think of an answer. If you want to read up on recursive queries: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-recursive-query/

The problem is that "first" and "second" tables are not completely equals (ie the data is not directly correspond, or equal to one another), thus can't be just directly joined.

@ThorstenKettner I come up with using lag() for each of two ids, to choose unique ones, but still probably not able to handle all the cases

Give me some time to think this through :-)

You've made a mistake that is quite common unfortunately: You've tried to write a query before getting the algorithm straight. First think through what the query is to do exactly. Only then write the query.
Below I'll try to get the algorithm first, then the query.
In the request comments you have clarified that the table shown is actally two tables. To avoid ambiguities I'll call the column id of the first table id1. This gives us two tables:

t1 (id1, a, a1)
t2 (id2, b, b1).

Candidates
The final result is a combination of rows. In your case one row for (id1, id2) = (1, 2), and another with (id1, id2) = (2, 4). ID1 3 is dismissed from the result set. This means that a result set does not necessarily include all id1.
If table t1 contained only id1 = 1 and table t2 only id2 = 1 and 2, we'd have the joined result:



id1
id2




1
1


1
2



Your requirement is "I need to select distinct values of id1", then it is obvious that we would only include one of the two id2 and dismiss the other. This means that a result set does not necessarily include all id2 either.
As we join rows from t1 and t2, we can get any a and b combined and any a1 and b1 comnbined. Your query shows that you want to apply two rules here: b must be greater than or equal to a and b1 must be greater than or equal to a1.
From the following join result



id1
a
id2
b
diff




1
1
4
0
-1


1
1
5
1
0


2
2
4
0
-2


2
2
5
1
-1


3
3
4
0
-3


3
3
5
1
-2



we would dismiss the following IDs from the candidate result rows, because all their joined rows end up with a negative (b-a):

id1 = 2
id1 = 3
id2 = 4

As explained before and shown now, both IDs can have values that get completely dismissed from our candidate list.
Desired result
After selecting our candidates we get some combinations left. For some id1 this can be a single id2. For some id2 this can be a single id1. And for other IDs there may be many, many rows. For instance:



id1
a
id2
b
dif




1
1
4
1
0


1
1
5
2
1


1
1
6
3
2


2
2
5
2
0


2
2
6
3
1


3
3
6
3
0



The primary rule that you have stated in the request is that you only want distinct id1 and distinct id2 in the final result.
If we chose the third row (1, 6) for id1 = 1, that would dismiss the last row (3, 6) from the results, and we'd lose id1 = 3 completely. This can be avoided by choosing the first row for id1 = 1: (1,4). Considering this you stated a secondary rule in the request comments: You want as many result rows as possible. So for the joined result table just shown, you'd want a final result of three rows and dismiss any result of only two rows or less.
At last you stated this rule set in your request: "the differences between a and b, and then a1 and b2 are minimal". I suppose this tertiary rule is supposed to mean: you want to get as low a sum of (b-a) as possible. And the quaternary rule is then: you want to get as low a sum of (b1-a1) as possible.
Only now have we stated all rules and their priorities, and only now can we start writing the query.
The ranking
We have learnt that we must combine rows to a final result set and depending on which rows we pick, we may end up with more or less result rows and lower or higher value differences. This means that we must first get all combinations in order to choose from them. For the last mentioned joined table, we'd get these options:



id1
a
id2
b
dif




1
1
4
1
0


2
2
5
2
0


3
3
6
3
0






id1
a
id2
b
dif




1
1
4
1
0


2
2
6
3
1






id1
a
id2
b
dif




1
1
5
2
1


2
2
6
3
1






id1
a
id2
b
dif




1
1
5
2
1


3
3
6
3
0






id1
a
id2
b
dif




1
1
6
3
2


2
2
5
2
0



Now we can rank them, getting the first option on top, because it has more rows than the others. If there were more than one row on top with the same number of rows, we'd have to check further: We'd look up the (b - a) sums and at last the (b1 - a1) sums. Thus we'd either get a single best row or multiple best rows. In the latter case we'd pick one of those top row sets arbitrarily.
The query
In order to produce all the options first, we use a recursive query where we join one row with a second, then with a third, etc. as long as we don't get duplicates. The result is rows with an array of ID pairs and a diff sum each, e.g. result #1 = [(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)], diff_sum = 9. We'll rank the rows as shown, pick the best row and then use it to select the original rows for the final result.
with recursive
  candidates as
  (
    select
      t1.id1, t1.a, t1.a1,
      t2.id2, t2.b, t2.b1
    from t1
    join t2 on t2.b - t1.a >= 0
            and t2.b1 - t1.a1 >= 0
    
  ),
  combinations (arr_pairs, last_id1, arr_id2, diff1, diff2) as
  (
    select
      array[(id1, id2)],
      id1,
      array[id2],
      b - a,
      b1 - a1
    from candidates
    union all
    select
      com.arr_pairs || (can.id1, can.id2),
      can.id1,
      com.arr_id2 || can.id2,
      com.diff1 + can.b - can.a,
      com.diff2 + can.b1 - can.a1
    from combinations com 
    join candidates can on can.id1 > com.last_id1
                          and can.id2 != all (com.arr_id2)
  ),
  best_combination as
  (
    select *
    from combinations
    order by cardinality(arr_pairs) desc, diff1, diff2
    fetch first row only
  ),
  best_combination_rows as
  (
    select bcr.id1, bcr.id2
    from unnest((select arr_pairs from best_combination)) as bcr (id1 int, id2 int)
  )
select *
from candidates
where (id1, id2) in (select id1, id2 from best_combination_rows)
order by id1;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/LqggdaM_
Disclaimer: I am neither a math guy fluent with combinations, nor a PostgreSQL developer, so it is possible to get this slightly more effective here and there.

perfect, thank you.
so you indeed ended up with a recursive query. I had a look yesterday on the concept, but didn't understand how it could be applied to my case, because I don't understand how to implement kind of box with candidates from which I will read "destructively", ie remove by reading. Now I see, this could be done by iterating by kind of "cursor", which hold the position, and "fetch first row only".
Very interesting, and clear descriptive answer, thank you.
I'll use it and put into bookmarks

BTW, I actually come up with another solution.
Just wonder, am I missing something?
It actually gives the same answer as yours, and also solves my initial sample.
Here it is:
with data as
(select * from t1 cross join t2)
select distinct on (id2, b, b1) *
from data
where b >= a and b1 >= a1
order by id2, b, b1, b-a, b1-a1;
I'm not playin, really wonder if it's ok. Seems working.

argh, nevermind, found that actually yours solve my original table/problem, while mine gives two duplicate id/id1 as a result.
thanks :)

Could you please give any advices on how to adopt this method for 'big' tables?
I thought to create a view which cross join like 4000 on 15000 rows (seems quite normal), but trying to play with recursive query I got "no space left on device"

Finding the optimal data set of many combinations is a complex task, and SQL might just not be the adequate tool for this. SQL works on data sets. This is why we get the candidates first, then all combinations of these candidates, then the best of the combinations. We can not say "give us just one combination, then give us another one, compare the two, dismiss the worse of them, get a third combination, ..." as we might do in a programming language.

We want to look at all possible combinations. With IDs 1, 2, 3 in one table and 6, 7, 8 in the other, we'd already get 33 combinations (if I'm not mistaken): (16) (17) (18) (26) (27) (28) (36) (37) (38) (16 27) (16 28) (17 26) (17 28) (18 26) (18 27) (16 37) (16 38) (17 36) (17 38) (18 36) (18 37) (26 37) (26 38) (27 36) (27 38) (28 36) (28 37) (16 27 38) (16 28 37) (17 26 38) (17 28 36) (18 26 37) (18 27 36). Of these we must find the best option (one of the triples in this case). With more IDs this set of combinations gets huge.

Now let's imagine we find one triple very early. In that case we wouldn't have to consider singles and couples anymore. We would dismiss them right away. This is probably not possible in SQL. PostgreSQL has a built-in programming language PL/pgSQL. It may be a better option to use this instead of the set-based SQL.
